# setOnPreferenceClickListener on multiple preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, clicklistener

If we have multiple preferences like checkbox, edittext, list preferences, how to setOnPreferenceClickListener on these items at once instead of setting the listener on each preference. I need to support for latest devices ( > 4.0 ).

Say, If we have 10 preferences under different category and if we need to set the listener on all of it, i don't want to find all the preference separately and write the code for it. Use some loops to get single all preferences at once and Is there any way we can write only one listener and use switch case?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using old fashion preference style (you use `addPreferencesFromResource()`) then you can override `onPreferenceTreeClick()` function.

If you are using modern - fragment based preferences, then you should override `onPreferenceStartFragment()`. I haven't tested this solution yet, but according to documentation this is what you are looking for.

Both functions pass as argument Preference object, where you can find preference key... First option worked for me, and yea, I'm kind of old fashioned guy.

**EDIT**

When using fragment based activity: You don't have to set click listener on every item. Just override `onPreferenceTreeClick()` in `PreferenceFragment` class. Here is example.

```
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
        switch (preference.getKey()){
              case "key_1":
                  //Do your stuff
                  break;
        }
        return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @user1557434 I am using fragment based preference. Or is there any other way by which I can setOnPreferenceClickListener on the preferences?